# Update android livedata with a firestore query with parameter (MVVM, Repository)

Tags: android, mvvm, google-cloud-firestore, android-livedata

I want to implement an android app with the MVVM model. The problem is that I can't find a way to update the data in the ViewModel with a Firestore call that contains a parameter. The repository class is responsible for loading the data, which either fetches it from the local room-database (works) or otherwise from firestore.

My question:

Is my implementation correct? Getting the data from the room-database works. But loading the data from Firestore doesn't work. I think the problem is that the firestore-query has not been executed yet when the getFoods function in the FirestoreFoodWebservice-Class returns. What can I do to fix this?

My architecture looks like this:

```
MainActivity -> MainActivitiyViewModel -> FoodRepository -> 
(
    if (data is in room database) return from database
    else (get data from firestore webservice)
)
```

MainActivity:

```
mainActivityViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(MainActivityViewModel::class.java)
mainActivityViewModel.getFoodsFilteredByName().observe(this, Observer { foods ->
    run {
        searchResultAdapter.setData(foods)
        progressIndicator.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
    }
})
```

SearchResultAdapter:

```
fun setData(foods : List<Food>) {
    if (searchResult.isEmpty()) {
        searchResult = ArrayList(foods);
        notifyItemRangeInserted(0, searchResult.size)
        return
    }

    val result = DiffUtil.calculateDiff(object : DiffUtil.Callback() {
        override fun getOldListSize(): Int {
            return searchResult.size
        }

        override fun getNewListSize(): Int {
            return foods.size
        }

        override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItemPosition: Int, newItemPosition: Int): Boolean {
            return searchResult[oldItemPosition].foodName === foods[newItemPosition].foodName
        }

        override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItemPosition: Int, newItemPosition: Int): Boolean {
            val newFood = foods[newItemPosition]
            val oldFood = searchResult[oldItemPosition]
            return newFood == oldFood
        }
    })
    searchResult = ArrayList(foods)
    result.dispatchUpdatesTo(this)
}
```

MainActivityViewModel:

```
private val foodsFilteredByName: LiveData<List<Food>>
private val filterName = MutableLiveData<String>()

init {
    val foodsDao = FoodRoomDatabase.getDatabase(application, viewModelScope).foodDao()
    val webservice = FirestoreFoodWebservice()
    repository = FoodRepository(foodsDao, webservice)
    foodsFilteredByName  = Transformations.switchMap(filterName) { c -> repository.getFoods(c) }
}

...

fun setFilter(name: String ) {
    filterName.value = name

}
```

FoodRepository:

```
fun getFoods(foodName: String): MutableLiveData<List<Food>> {
    // if data exists in room database return the data
    // else:
    var foods: List<Food> = webservice.getFoods(foodName)
    val data = MutableLiveData<List<Food>>()
    data.value = foods

    return data
}
```

FirestoreFoodWebservice:

(Before switching to MVVM I had the query in the MainActivity. There the query worked.)

```
fun getFoods(foodName: String): List<Food> {
    val query = // create firestore query

    query.get().addOnSuccessListener { result ->
        for (document in result) {
            var food = Food()
            // fill food with data from result
            foods.add(food)
        }
    }.addOnFailureListener { /*  ToDo: Implement */ }
    return foods
    // Edit: Changed foodNames to foods
}
```

Comment: The problem is, as you suggested, that `FirestoreFoodWebservice#getFoods` returns before the firestore query returns. You can fix this by either (1) make `getFoods` wait until the query returns, (2) make `getFoods` to return the query result using callback, or (3) make `getFoods` to return a `LiveData` instance. Can't decide which one is better atm, because there seem to be another problem in your code regarding `Room`. Normally you shouldn't be able to tell synchronously whether some data is present in database. Please provide the full `FoodRepository#getFoods` code.

Comment: @SanlokLee Thank you. (3) works for now. You are right that synchronous loading of data from room does not work.  The getFoods method has not yet been fully implemented. After some research I now see that my implementation would violate the "single source of truth" principle. If you post your comment as an answer I will mark it as correct. I'll post an answer when the implementation works.